# Can I debug JavaScript code in google script editor (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was creating a simple web application using HtmlService in Google Apps script. I want to debug the JavaScript code(Client side) in the HTML file. Is there any way ?

I know the process for server side function.

Thank You In Advance !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use your web browser's built-in utilities to debug client-side Javascript.  In Google Chrome, you can open the Developer Tools by pressing Ctrl-Shift-I or opening the menu and selecting More tools --> Developer tools.

Comment: This did not work for me. I can open dev tools, but I don't see anything that looks like my client-side apps script listed there. If I add 'debugger;' to my code, it stops in userCodeAppPanel, but again, it looks nothing like my code (not even a compressed/obfuscated version of it).

Comment: Apparently this approach will not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520959/debugging-client-side-code-from-google-apps-script

Comment: This answer is 5 years old and I'm sure much has changed in Chrome since then.

Comment: How can I place a breakpoint in the .gs code, when I invoke the app-script functions via javascript using google.script.run